# can ec2 instances automatically delete and relaunch with different connection details?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have recently noted that an ec2 instance in my AWS Account has a launch time that is at a time from yesterday, and its Public IPv4 DNS is different from what it was previously. Is it possible that my ec2 instance automatically got relaunched with a different IPv4 DNS, or is it more likely that someone else has deleted the old instance and launched a new one within my aws account? If so is there a way to review activity on my aws account if I haven't previously turned cloudtrail on? Even if it means paying some extra money for AWS Support Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is **Stopped** and later **Started** it will have a different Public IP address (unless an Elastic IP was assigned to it).

Also, if EC2 instances are part of an Auto Scaling group, then instances will be **Terminated** when a scale-in event happens and new instances will be **Launched** when a scale-out event occurs.

You should definitely check your CloudTrail trails. There is a **default event history for the past 90-days** that should show what happened to the instance. You can create your own Trail to keep these records for longer periods (highly encouraged!). It does not require a subscription to AWS Support.

The confusing pricing for CloudTrail is available at: [AWS CloudTrail pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/pricing/)